# How i change a pie chart color with ng2-charts and chartsJS?

Tags: angular, typescript, elasticsearch, chart.js, ng2-charts

I have a pie chart with this code

```
<div class="chart-wrapper">
    <canvas baseChart [data]="values" [labels]="keys" [chartType]="pieChartType" [options]="pieChartOptions" [plugins]="pieChartPlugins" [colors]="pieChartColors" [legend]="pieChartLegend">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

And i have my typeScript with this

```
` 
  /*public pieChartColors: Color = [
    {
      backgroundColor: [
        '#193498',
        '#113CFC',
        '#1597E5',
        '#69DADB'
      ]
    }
  ]*/

  constructor() {
    monkeyPatchChartJsTooltip();
    monkeyPatchChartJsLegend();
  }

}
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Montserrat";
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 13;
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'black';
`
```

I'm using angular and everytime that I'm trying to changing a color properties i got "Failed to Compiled error" and the canvas where i insert the class make my component crash.

---

```
    <div class="chart-wrapper">
    <canvas baseChart [data]="values" 
    [labels]="keys" 
    [chartType]="pieChartType" 
    [options]="pieChartOptions" 
    [plugins]="pieChartPlugins"
    [legend]="pieChartLegend"><!--[colors]="pieChartColors"-->
  </canvas>
</div>
```

the commented part its the class that will be using in the typescript component, the commented part goes inside the canvas markup.

```
    public pieChartColors: Color = [
    {
      backgroundColor: [
        '#193498',
        '#113CFC',
        '#1597E5',
        '#69DADB'
      ]
    }
  ]
```

And this part is causing the problem with the chart.

```
Type '{ backgroundColor: string[]; }[]' has no properties in common with type 'Color'.ts(2559)
```

This is the error.

Comment: Why is the /* there? is that part of your code?

Comment: Cuz that part it´s making my component crash

Comment: You never close the comment in the code you shared. Do you have more code?